# Fixing documentclass{standalone} with a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, document-classes

I created a script which generates 3D visualizations of tensors like this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \def\x{2}
    \def\y{2}
    \def\z{3}
    \def\yscale{0.850000}
    \def\zslant{1.000000}
    \def\xlab{x}
    \def\ylab{y}
    \def\zlab{z}
    \def\gridcol{black!80}
    \def\shadecolA{white}
    \def\shadecolB{black!20}
    \tikzset{
        grid matrix/.style={
            nodes in empty cells,
            matrix of nodes,
            column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            nodes={
                rectangle,
                draw=gray,
                minimum height=1cm,
                anchor=center,
                align=center,
                text width=1cm,
                text height=2ex,
                text depth=0.5ex,
                inner sep=0pt,
                outer sep=0pt,
            }
        },
        grid matrix/.default=1.2em
    }

    \begin{scope}

    % top matrix
    \begin{scope}[transform canvas={xslant=\zslant, yscale=\yscale, shift={(-0.5*\z, 0.5 * \x)}, },transform shape]
    \draw[color=black, thick, ] (-0.5* \z,-0.5* \x) rectangle (0.5* \z, 0.5* \x);
    \shade[bottom color=\shadecolA, top color=\shadecolB] (-0.5* \z,-0.5* \x) rectangle (0.5* \z, 0.5* \x);

    \matrix (top) [grid matrix]{
        |[fill=none]| 4 & |[fill=none]| 8 & |[fill=none]| 12 \\
        |[fill=none]| 2 & |[fill=none]| 4 & |[fill=green]| 6 \\
    };
    \node [above, rotate=90, text width=\x * 1cm, align=center] at (top.west) {\xlab};
    \end{scope}

    % front matrix
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-0.5*\z, -0.5 * \y)}]
    \draw[color=black, thick, fill=\shadecolA] (-0.5* \z,-0.5* \y) rectangle (0.5* \z, 0.5* \y);
    %\shade[left color=gray!10, right color=black!60] (-0.5* \z,-0.5* \y) rectangle (0.5* \z, 0.5* \y);

    \matrix (front) [grid matrix]{
        |[fill=none]| 1 & |[fill=none]| 2 & |[fill=green]| 3 \\
        |[fill=red]| 1 & |[fill=red]| 2 & |[fill=red]| 3 \\
    };
    \node [below, text width=\z * 1cm, align=center] at (front.south) {\zlab};
    \node [above, rotate=90, text width=\y * 1cm, align=center] at (front.west) {\ylab};
    \end{scope}

    % side matrix
    \begin{scope}[transform canvas={yslant=1/\zslant, xscale=\yscale*\zslant, shift={(0.5*\x,-0.5*\y)}, },transform shape]
    \draw[color=black, thick] (-0.5* \x,-0.5* \y) rectangle (0.5* \x, 0.5* \y);
    \shade[left color=\shadecolA, right color=\shadecolB] (-0.5* \x,-0.5* \y) rectangle (0.5* \x, 0.5* \y);

    \matrix (side) [grid matrix]{
        |[fill=green]| 1 & |[fill=none]| 2 \\
        |[fill=red]| 3 & |[fill=red]| 4 \\
    };
    \end{scope}
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output; cropped by hand]

However, I'd like to re-use this figure and combine it with other figures.
Therefore, I tried to change `\documentclass{minimal}` to `\documentclass{standalone}`.

Result:

[image: standalone output]

How can I fix this and crop the cuboid to the correct size?

Comment: Does `line join=bevel` or `line join=round` help ?

Comment: `transform canvas` as you use, push slanted matrix out of bounding box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transform canvas` as you use, push slanted matrix out of picture bounding box. as possible solution is define (without `transform canvas`) an auxiliary empty node ad top right corner of cube:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=0mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\x{2}
    \def\y{2}
    \def\z{3}
    \def\yscale{0.850000}
    \def\zslant{1.000000}
    \def\xlab{x}
    \def\ylab{y}
    \def\zlab{z}
    \def\gridcol{black!80}
    \def\shadecolA{white}
    \def\shadecolB{black!20}
    \tikzset{
        grid matrix/.style={
            nodes in empty cells,
            matrix of nodes,
            column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            nodes={
                rectangle,
                draw=gray,
                minimum height=1cm,
                anchor=center,
                align=center,
                text width=1cm,
                text height=2ex,
                text depth=0.5ex,
                inner sep=0pt,
                outer sep=0pt,
            }
        },
        grid matrix/.default=1.2em
    }

    \node[coordinate,above=4\z,right=4\x,label={}] {};% <--- new node
    \begin{scope}
    % top matrix
    \begin{scope}[transform canvas={xslant=\zslant, yscale=\yscale, shift={(-0.5*\z, 0.5 * \x)}, },transform shape]
    \draw[color=black, thick, ] (-0.5* \z,-0.5* \x) rectangle (0.5* \z, 0.5* \x);
    \shade[bottom color=\shadecolA, top color=\shadecolB] (-0.5* \z,-0.5* \x) rectangle (0.5* \z, 0.5* \x);

    \matrix (top) [grid matrix]{
        |[fill=none]| 4 & |[fill=none]| 8 & |[fill=none]| 12 \\
        |[fill=none]| 2 & |[fill=none]| 4 & |[fill=green]| 6 \\
    };
    \node [above, rotate=90, text width=\x * 1cm, align=center] at (top.west) {\xlab};
    \end{scope}

    % front matrix
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-0.5*\z, -0.5 * \y)}]
    \draw[color=black, thick, fill=\shadecolA] (-0.5* \z,-0.5* \y) rectangle (0.5* \z, 0.5* \y);
    %\shade[left color=gray!10, right color=black!60] (-0.5* \z,-0.5* \y) rectangle (0.5* \z, 0.5* \y);

    \matrix (front) [grid matrix]{
        |[fill=none]| 1 & |[fill=none]| 2 & |[fill=green]| 3 \\
        |[fill=red]| 1 & |[fill=red]| 2 & |[fill=red]| 3 \\
    };
    \node [below, text width=\z * 1cm, align=center] at (front.south) {\zlab};
    \node [above, rotate=90, text width=\y * 1cm, align=center] at (front.west) {\ylab};
    \end{scope}

    % side matrix
    \begin{scope}[transform canvas={yslant=1/\zslant, xscale=\yscale*\zslant, shift={(0.5*\x,-0.5*\y)}, },transform shape]
    \draw[color=black, thick] (-0.5* \x,-0.5* \y) rectangle (0.5* \x, 0.5* \y);
    \shade[left color=\shadecolA, right color=\shadecolB] (-0.5* \x,-0.5* \y) rectangle (0.5* \x, 0.5* \y);

    \matrix (side) [grid matrix]{
        |[fill=green]| 1 & |[fill=none]| 2 \\
        |[fill=red]| 3 & |[fill=red]| 4 \\
    };
    \end{scope}
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this hint.
I solved it now by drawing aditinal invisible, untransformed rectangles behind the transformed visible surface.
This keeps my script size-adjustable.

Comment: @Hoeze, good solution. happy tex-ing!